# Student Attendance Report within a PIVOT Table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to record the attendance of my students that attend my courses. Courses are different lengths and times and I just need to record if a student is (P)resent (L)ate (A)sent. I record the attendance in 1 table and display the records in a pivot table based on the date attended. I am a newby and just can't workout this code to include all the details I need to show. id, bid, fullname, nickname, company_idno, (P)(L)(A).

Please could someone look at my code and tell me how to add this information to the pivot table.

**This is what I want to show**

[image: This is what I want to show]

**This is where I store the information**

[image: This is where I store the information]

**This is table1**

[image: This is table1]

**This is table2**

[image: This is table2]

At the moment I achieved the look I want but use 2 tables and use CSS to fix the widths of table 1 and place table 2 next to it.

I realize this is terrible practice and of course, I get odd results across different platforms, especially iOS which put a 47px gap between the 2 tables which I can't seem to remove also.

I want just want table 2 to show all the information. I can only show 3 fields, id, date, pla. How to add fullname, nickname and company_idno ??

Table 1

```
<table id="tblplanames" >  
        <td id="tdplabc">sid</td>  
        <td id="tdplabc">bid</td>   
        <td id="tdplacid" style="text-align: center">Cid</td>
        <td id="tdplafn" style="text-align: center">Fullname</td>
        <td id="tdplann" style="text-align: center">Nickname</td>
<?php
                $sql13="SELECT * FROM students WHERE classno='$id' ORDER BY bluecard_no ASC ";
        $sql_row13=mysqli_query($link,$sql13);
        while($sql_res13=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_row13))      {
        $stsid=$sql_res13["id"];
        $stidno=$sql_res13["company_idno"];
        $stbluecard_no=$sql_res13["bluecard_no"];
        $stfullname=$sql_res13["fullname"];
        $stnickname=$sql_res13["nickname"];
        ?>
    <tr>    
        <td id="tdplabc"><a href=edit_student.php?id=<?php echo $stsid ?>><?php echo $stsid; ?></td>
        <td id="tdplabc"><a href=edit_student.php?id=<?php echo $stsid ?>><?php echo $stbluecard_no; ?></td>
        <td id="tdplacid"><a href=edit_student.php?id=<?php echo $stsid ?>><?php echo $stidno; ?></td>
        <td id="tdplafn"><a href=edit_student.php?id=<?php echo $stsid ?>><?php echo $stfullname; ?></td>
        <td id="tdplann"><a href=edit_student.php?id=<?php echo $stsid ?>><?php echo $stnickname; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Table 2

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT date 
        FROM attendance
        WHERE classno = $id
        ORDER BY DATE";
$res = $link->query($sql);   // mysqli query
while ($row = $res->fetch_row()) {
    $dates[] = $row[0];
}
/***********************************
* Table headings                   *
************************************/
$emptyRow = array_fill_keys($dates,'');
// format dates
foreach ($dates as $k=>$v) {
    $dates[$k] = date('d-M', strtotime($v));
}
$heads = "<table id='tblpla'>\n";
$heads .= "<tr><td>sid</td><td>" . join('</td><td>', $dates) . "</td></tr>\n";
/***********************************
* Main data                        *
************************************/
$sql = "SELECT date, sid, pla, bluecard_no
        FROM attendance
        WHERE classno = $id
        ORDER BY bluecard_no";
$res = $link->query($sql);
$sid='';
$tdata = '';
while (list($d, $sn, $s, $bcn) = $res->fetch_row()) {
    if ($sid != $sn) {
        if ($sid) {
            $tdata .= "<tr><td>$sid</td><td>" . join('</td><td>', $rowdata). "</td></tr>\n";
        }
        $rowdata = $emptyRow;
        $sid = $sn;
    }
    $rowdata[$d] = $s;
}
$tdata .= "<tr><td>$sid</td><td>" . join('</td><td>', $rowdata). "</td></tr>\n";
$tdata .= "</table\n";
        echo $heads;
        echo $tdata;
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I am still practicing and once the code works I will change to be more secure from SQL injection. BTW this is not a commercial app, its just available for me to use in my daily worklife. Comment noted and appreciated. My problem is I can't display the fields I want from Table 2, I can only have id field with date and P, L or A?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.olumns 
     , y.ou
     , a.ctually
     , w.ant
  FROM students s
  JOIN attendance a
  ON a.classno = s.classno
 WHERE s.classno = :id 
 ORDER 
    BY s.bluecard_no ASC 
     , a.date";
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have the data in Table 2 so, don't need to JOIN table 1 but 1 am unable to display all the fields from table 2, I can't work out how to have more than 3 fields eg, id,date, pla. I have fullname, nickname, sid in attendance table but cannot display this information.

Comment: The first query just to make Table 1, because I don't know how to display all the fields I need in Table2. I can only show 1 field on the left column but can't show more than 1 column. I need id, fullname, nickname, company_idno on the left (columns 1-4) and dates and PLA on the right as my first picture. Can you help me?? I would be very grateful for the help. I'm sure its easy for a skilled guy like you :)

Comment: Well, the first step is to fix table2. It should comprise just 2 or 3 columns: student_id*, date*, and (optionally) status (present/absent/late).

Comment: I managed to do that already, the pictures are actual screenshots of the code working. But I must have student_id, fullname, nickname, company_idno, date and status (present/absent/late) all in 1 table. Any advice how to do that?

Comment: Until the question properly reflects the problem, it's a bit hard to help.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I am fairly new to coding html/php and self-taught, so my wording may cause confusion as I can't explain myself super clearly in programmers speaking language. The problem is that to produce the results I want, I have to use 2 tables and sit them side by side, but this causes problems between devices, in chrome, and firefox no problem, but in iOS there is a 47px gap between the 2 tables which looks ugly. So the question, is can I have all the information in table 1 and 2 in a single table but with the same information??

Answer (score 0):

```
public function get_members_for_attendence()
{
    $date = $this->input->post('choose_date');
    $sql = 'SELECT a.date, c.member_name,c.member_join_date,c.member_payment_date,c.member_exp_date,c.member_payment_date,c.member_contact, c.member_reg_id,
            CASE
                WHEN a.status = "absent" THEN "Absent"
                WHEN a.status = "present" THEN "Present"
                ELSE "Not Taken"
            END as attendence_status
            FROM member_reg AS c 
            LEFT JOIN attendence AS a ON a.member_reg_id = c.member_reg_id AND a.date = "'.$date.'"';
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result();
}
```

**For CodeIgniter 3**
**it worked for me**